# Summing total of foreign key relationship and dealing with null

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have query which calculates the items in my receipts and returns their data for report generation. I have a scenario where some items are returned so I have to take that into account when getting this data by getting all operations with return_item_id.

Item Table:

id

name

Operation Table:

return_item_id

amount

ReceiptItem Table:

item_id

price

amount

```
select
cps_item.name as "item.name",
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY e.create_ts) as "row",
e.amount - SUM(cps_operation.amount) as "amount",
e.price as "price",
e.amount * e.price as "sum"
from cps_receipt_items e  
left join cps_item ON e.item_id = cps_item.code
left join cps_operation ON e.id = cps_operation.return_item_id
where e.receipt_id = ${sell}
and e.item_id is not null
group by cps_item.name, e.amount, e.price, e.create_ts;
```

The expected result I want is to show all amounts correctly, however what happens is when SUM(cps_operation.amount) returns Null because there was no return operation it returns empty values instead of just show the amount without the result of SUM(cps_operation.amount).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use coalesce

```
select
cps_item.name as "item.name",
ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY e.create_ts) as "row",
e.amount - coalesce(SUM(cps_operation.amount),0) as "amount",
e.price as "price",
e.amount * e.price as "sum"
from cps_receipt_items e  
left join cps_item ON e.item_id = cps_item.code
left join cps_operation ON e.id = cps_operation.return_item_id
where e.receipt_id = ${sell}
and e.item_id is not null
group by cps_item.name, e.amount, e.price, e.create_ts;
```

Comment: Thanks that works I was wondering if it is possible if in the where I can use this result to only return greater than 0